# Sort Related List rows (of LWC) normally, Alphabetically and by price

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, related-list, sort

I am trying to sort the rows of my realted list. First I was using a standard sort function but it was not sorting the prices correctly. Ex; it was setting $117,000 lower than $68 000 because 1 is lower than 6. I have tried to implement something else but when I interact with the row this message appears:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getopportunities from '@salesforce/apex/oppcontrol.getopportunities';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';



const Columns = [
    {label: 'Opp Name', fieldName: 'link', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'Name'}, type: 'text'}, sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'accountlink', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{label: {fieldName: 'Account_Name'}}, sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'End User',fieldName: 'End_User_link', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{label: {fieldName: 'End_User__c'}}, sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount', type: 'currency', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Close Date', fieldName: 'CloseDate', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Stage Name', fieldName: 'StageName', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Market', fieldName: 'Market__c', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry__c', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Segment', fieldName: 'Segment__c', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Transaction Type', fieldName: 'Transaction_Type__c', sortable: "true"}
    ]

export default class Finalopp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;  
    @track opportunities;
    error;
    @track cols=Columns;
    wiredOpp;
    rowLimit =20;
    rowOffSet =0;
    baseData;
    @wire(getopportunities, {val: '$recordId'}, {limitSize: this.rowLimit}, {offset: this.rowOffSet})
    wiredOpp({error, data}){
        if(data){
           this.opportunities = data.map((row) => {
            return this.mapOpp(row);
           })
        this.baseData = this.opportunities
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.opportunities = undefined;
        }
        console.log(data);
        console.log(error);
    }

    mapOpp(row){
        console.log(row);
        var AccName = ''
        var Acclink = ''
        if(row.AccountId != undefined){
            AccName = `${row.Account.Name}`
            Acclink = `/${row.AccountId}`
        }
        var UserName = ' ';
        var Userlink = ' ';
        if (row.End_User__c != undefined){
            UserName = `${row.End_User__r.Name}`
            Userlink = `/${row.End_User__r.Id}`
        }
        return{...row,
           Amount: `${row.Amount}`,
           StageName: `${row.StageName}`,
           Name: `${row.Name}`,
           link: `/${row.Id}`,
           End_User__c: UserName,
           End_User_link: Userlink,
           Account_Name: AccName,
           accountlink: Acclink 


        };
    }

    handleSortData(event){
        const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
        console.log('MVK-->'+JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        const cloneData = [...this.opportunities];
        const numberPrimer = (value) => ((''+value).match(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/)? parseFloat(value):value);
        cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1, numberPrimer));
        this.opportunities = cloneData;
        this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
        this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}

    sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
        const key = primer ? function(x) {
                             return primer(x[field]);
                         } : function(x) {
                             return x[field];
                         };

        return function(a, b) {
            a = key(a);
            b = key(b);
        return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    };
}

     
     handleSearch(event){
        var searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        this.opportunities = this.baseData.filter((row) => {
            for (let field of Object.values(row)) {
                if (field && field.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
    }}
```

```
<template>
    
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">
        <lightning-card title="Opportunity" icon-name="standard:opportunity"></lightning-card>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-bottom_x-small slds-p-left_x-small">
            <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleSearch}></lightning-input></div></div>
    
        <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:400px; width: auto" >
             <lightning-datatable
                 data={opportunities} 
                 columns={cols} 
                 key-field="id"  
                 show-row-number-column="true" 
                 sorted-by={sortedBy}
                 sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                 onsort={handleSortData}
                 hide-checkbox-column="true">
                 
                </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
         
    
 
</template>
```

````
public class oppcontrol {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=True)
 public static List<Opportunity> getopportunities(Id val) {
  return [SELECT Id, StageName, End_User__c, Name, Amount, CloseDate, Market__c, Industry__c, Segment__c, Transaction_Type__c, Account.Name, End_User__r.Name, End_User__r.Id 
          FROM Opportunity 
          WHERE AccountId=:val OR End_User__c=:val];
}
}```
````